# Get string between function with index

Tags: php

I've been using this function

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
  $string = ' ' . $string;
  $ini = strpos($string, $start);
  if ($ini == 0) return '';
  $ini += strlen($start);
  $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
  return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
```

since ages and everything worked fine but now I need to specify index, so for example in code like this:

```
<abc>Max</def><abc>Mike</def><abc>Roy</def>
```

I wanna be able to get "Mike", so I want to use

```
get_string_between($string, "<abc>", "</def>", 1)
```

I couldn't find any solution and I can't use Regex. Thank you for help.

Comment: Why can't you use regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you shouldn't be able to use regex. `preg_quote` escapes any character having a special meaning in regular expressions in order to become a literal. Passing the delimiter (which is arbitrary in PHP - commonly the slash `/` is used) also escapes that one.

```
<?php
declare (strict_types=1);

function get_string_between(string $string, string $start, string $end, int $index = 0)
{
  if(false === ($c = preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($start, '/') . '(.*?)' . preg_quote($end, '/') . '/us', $string, $matches)))
    return false;

  if($index < 0)
    $index += $c;

  return $index < 0 || $index >= $c
    ? false
    : $matches[1][$index]
  ;
}

$s = '<abc>Max</def><abc>Mike</def><abc>Roy</def>';

var_dump(get_string_between($s, '<abc>', '</def>'    ));  // Max
var_dump(get_string_between($s, '<abc>', '</def>',  1));  // Mike
// negative means from the end
var_dump(get_string_between($s, '<abc>', '</def>', -1));  // Roy
```

Comment: This is much less overhead and code than the strpos cruft. (And I would guess OPs "can't use…" was only based on the html/regex/parsing meme.)

Comment: @mario yes, I guess the OP just wasn't aware of `preg_qoute`. I've added this to the description to be more verbose.

Comment: @mario It's hard to predict overhead. Actually regex *can* have a lot of overhead. It may vary on the expression complexity and the input data. This expression is fairly simple. However, in non-time-critical situations I frequently prefer readble expressive code over best performance when the overhead is not *too* heavy.

Comment: Agreed, and would also just base this on readability. But even for complex patterns, the PCRE VM usually outruns the Zend VM anyway (barring recursive patterns or too many placeholders / excessive backtracking).

Comment: @mario Furthermore to be noticed that the ancient string functions im PHP may break on multibyte strings while the `mbstring` extension isn't enabled by default and can turn out tricky to juggle with different encodings. The `preg_` switch `u` works with UTF-8 compatible character sets which most of the charsets are.

Answer (score 1):

Use the $offset param of [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) to skip previous occurences.

- Predeclare `$ini` with zero
- Wrap your `$ini = strpos(…, $ini)` in a [`do`](http://php.net/do)/[`while`](http://php.net/while) loop.
- Make it loop when `$index--` is larger than zero.
- And increment `&& ++$ini` right in the condition, so [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) really looks for the next occurence.